# Conditional probabilities when partitioned by a 3rd element

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(S, \mathcal B, P)$ be a probability space. Let $A, B, C \in \mathcal B$ with $P(B)>0$ and $P(C)>0$. If $B$ and $C$ are independent, show that

$P(A|B) = P(A|B \cap C)P(C) + P(A|B\cap C^c)P(C^c)$.

I'm a little confused on where to start. I think it's clear that $C$ and $C^c$ make a partition of $S$, and that has something to do with it. This proof seems intuitive, but I can't figure out the exact rules that allow me to proceed with this proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is true is that $B \cap C$ and $B \cap C^c$ make a partition of $B$. Hence, we get that:
$$
P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C^c)}{P(B)} \\ = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)P(C)}{P(B)P(C)} + \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C^c)P(C^c)}{P(B)P(C^c)} \\
= \frac{P(A \cap B\cap C) }{P(B \cap C)} P(C) + \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C^c)}{P(B \cap C^c)} P(C^c)  
\\
= P(A | B \cap C) P(C) + P(A | B \cap C^c) P(C^c)
$$

Comment: Great, thank you! Multiplying the top and bottom by $P(C)$ and $P(C^c)$ was something I completely forgot to do.

Comment: You are welcome!